# Power Manager Doesn't Show Battery Charging

Tags: 11.10, power-management

I just upgraded to 11.10 last night and I noticed that power manager doesn't update the battery charge %. It's been plugged in for hours and the energy hasn't changed (it neither went up or down). Is this a bug with the new version?

Answer (score 1):

In 11.10 Icon characteristics have changed a bit. If it is charged or have just started discharging you will see full battery. as it keep discharging you will see the battery icons showing it. When it have been discharged to certain extent and plugin AC power (Adapter) you will see thunder-icon showing it charging. If you want to knwo what currently is happening click the battery icon and it will say something like **Battery(charged)**